# Restar media hora en bash

Tags: bash

Estoy preparando un script en `bash` para manejar la inserción de unos datos en una tabla, pero necesito modificar la fecha de tal forma que tenga la hora actual, la misma hora en `UTC` y la misma hora en `UTC` menos media hora.

Por ejemplo:

1. Hora de inicio del script: 12:00
2. Hora de inicio del periodo: 09:30 (UTC - 30 MINUTOS)
3. Hora de fin del periodo: 10:00 (UTC)

Hasta ahora, el código que tengo escrito para esta parte es este:

```sh
FECHA_ACTUAL=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
FECHA_FIN=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
FECHA_INICIO=`date -d "$FECHA_FIN - 30 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

echo $FECHA_ACTUAL
echo $FECHA_INICIO
echo $FECHA_FIN
```

La parte de `date -d "$FECHA_FIN - 30 minutes"` la encontré por internet pero no me funciona.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué bash utilizas? En Linux lo de -30 minutes debería funcionarte, mientras que en MacOS no.

Comment: @fedorqui utilizo Bash. Es posible que no esté poniendo correctamente la secuencia de comandos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a poner lo siguiente:

```
FECHA_INICIO=$(date -u -d "30 minutes ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: no conocía la posibilidad de `ago`. Me ha funcionado tal como quería.

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de revisar un poco de la interesantísima documentación que proporciona la sección de "Relative items in date strings" a través del manual en `info` y también hice algunas pruebas con lo que haz intentado.

Lo que menciona @david es lo que se describe en esa sección sobre los tiempos relativos, con traducción propia.

> "Items relativos" ajustan la fecha (de la fecha actual si no se proporciona alguna) hacía atrás o hacía adelante.
>
> La unidad de tiempo puede estar precedida por un multiplicador, dado como un número opcionalmente con signo. Seguir un elemento relativo por la cadena "ago" es equivalente a preceder a la unidad por un multiplicador con valor -1. La cadena "tomorrow" vale un día en el futuro (equivalente a "day"), la cadena "yesterday" vale un día en el pasado (equivalente a "day ago").

Entonces se me ocurren varios ejemplos, por ejemplo, el de la respuesta da @david

```
date -u -d "30 minutes ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

que sería equivalente a

```
date -u -d "-30 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Por el multiplicador "-30 <unidades>" equivalente a poner "30 <unidades> ago".

Pero también podríamos pensar la forma de tu ejemplo.

```
date -u -d "$(date) -30 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Y funciona bien este ejemplo, pero si te diste cuenta del error que aparecía en tu código, mostraba algo como `Invalid date`, entonces es muy probable que sea por el formato. Trata de poner el formato de la fecha fin con la [letra "Z" al final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), letra "Z" de "zero time" o "Zulu time" como el ISO 8601 indica para el tiempo en UTC. "Zulu" en el alfabeto radiofónico, con uso del ejército, es para indicar la letra "Z".

Entonces tu código podría quedar del estilo

```
FECHA_ACTUAL=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
FECHA_FIN=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ"`
#                                     |
#       Nota la letra "Z" al final____|
FECHA_INICIO=`date -u -d "$FECHA_FIN - 30 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

echo $FECHA_ACTUAL
echo $FECHA_INICIO
echo $FECHA_FIN
```

Comment: A veces, [`date` hace cosas raras](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211796/40596)